# Best way to learn economics for an interested layperson with a mathematical background

Tags: reference-request, self-study

What's a good way for a mathematically-literate layperson who's interested in seriously learning economics?

I suppose the quick answer is "read a textbook", but 1) textbooks are boring, 2) they're expensive, and 3) for economics books, it seems that intro university-level books assume way less mathematical knowledge than the the typical scientist/engineer/STEM grad student (i.e. the type of "layperson" I'm referring to) has, while advanced and graduate level books use a lot of jargon and assume knowledge of introductory economics,

Ideally, it would be nice if there were "advanced pop science" economics books, sort of like [The Theoretical Minimum](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465075681), [Quantum field theory for the gifted amateur](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019969933X), or [The Road to Realty](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0679776311) for physics.

Comment: [Rational Choice](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/rational-choice) by Itzhak Gilboa comes close.

Comment: I hope you will get some good recommendations but honestly pop-science books are really not good place to seriously learn anything, due to the pop-part these won’t be rigorous. I think if you seriously want to learn and not just be entertained you will have to get some textbook at some point. Also it would help if you would narrow your request down to some area of economics there is unlikely to be any text covering the entirety of the profession especially not when it comes to pop-sci texts

Comment: If you're interested in some macro applications, Advanced Macroeconomics by Romer is pretty good. It's a masters/upper undergraduate level textbook so the math is higher level than an intro textbook and it's pretty fun stuff to work through

Comment: @Brennan in addition Romers Macro has some fun stuff in it - the footnote that mentions that someone asked Hall if he is on drugs during presentation of his random walk hypothesis made me laugh out laud :p